# Django run migrations over previous django project

Tags: django, django-migrations

I did a `pg_dump` on a Heroku app. Then I did a `pg_restore` on a local branch of the project that includes new models and fields. Then, I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and I got the message `no changes detected` (weird). Then, when I ran `python manage.py migrate` I get the typical error `ProgrammingError relation does not exists`. ¿What can I do to solve this?.

Comment: try `python manage.py makemigartions <app_name>` and then `python manage.py migrate <app_name>`

Comment: @qasimalbaqali Thanks for the answer, already tried that. :/

Comment: You can delete your database? To solve migrations problems, you can delete the migrations files in your apps and do again in fresh the makemigrations